# spring boot cookie csrf name

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have bean following this tutorial.

http://www.codesandnotes.be/2014/10/31/restful-authentication-using-spring-security-on-spring-boot-and-jquery-as-a-web-client/#comment-515

And it is working great, But I cant figure out where the `helloween` cookie name is set. How can I override the name of X-CSRF-TOKEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's handled in the JavaScript. [For example](https://github.com/codesandnotes/restsecurity/blob/3a1ed50e7c72df5bd576971b5fd445f7bab7ba1f/src/main/webapp/index.js#L15):

```
$.cookie('helloween', JSON.stringify(cookie));
```